# calling setter with an extra argument? - MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matlab-class

In a class with the dependent property `c`, I would like to call `c`'s setter with a third argument that equals `'a'` or `'b'`, choosing which independent property to alter in order to set `c`.

The code is

```
classdef test < handle
    properties
        a
        b
    end
    properties (Dependent = true)
        c
    end

    methods
        function c = get.c(obj)
            c = obj.a + obj.b;
        end

        function obj = set.c(obj, value, varargin)
            if(nargin == 2)
                obj.a = value - obj.b;
            end

            if(nargin == 3 && argin(3) == 'a') % how do I enter this loop?
                obj.a = value - obj.b;
            end

            if(nargin == 3 && argin(3) == 'b') % or this?
                obj.b = value - obj.a;
            end

        end
    end
end
```

This call works:

```
myobject.c = 5
```

But how do I call the setter with a third parameter equaling `'a'` or `'b'`?

Answer (score 0):

You can't. `set` always accepts only two arguments. You could work around it with an additional dependent property:

```
classdef test < handle

    properties
        a
        b
    end

    properties (Dependent = true)
        c
        d
    end

    methods
        function c = get.c(obj)
            c = obj.a + obj.b;
        end
        function d = get.d(obj)
            d = c;
        end

        function obj = set.c(obj, value)                
            obj.a = value - obj.b;
        end
        function obj = set.d(obj, value)                
            obj.b = value - obj.a;
        end

    end
end
```

or by choosing a different syntax and/or approach:

```
myObject.set_c(5,'a')  %// easiest; just use a function
myObject.c = {5, 'b'}  %// easy; error-checking will be the majority of the code
myObject.c('a') = 5    %// hard; override subsref/subsasgn; good luck with that
```

or something else creative :)

Comment: you might be able to do this if you override subsref

Comment: @janh: but you cannot use syntax like `myObject.c = 5`, you'd have to do something non-standard and perhaps unintuitive, like `myObject.c('a') = 5`

Comment: afaik you can't override `set.c(obj)` Matlab doesn't allow it. you can however, and as you pointed out, override subsref to mimic `set.c(obj, value)`. and yes, you then still need something like `myObject.c = {5, 'b'}`. I use `myObject.set_c` to work around Matlab disallowing overriding a getter in a subclass. all that said, the objects need to be refactored ;)